# Фотоальбом Light Box. Почему не работает Javascript?

Tags: html, css, javascript

javascript html css js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки уберите. Добавляется элемент, а не строка.

```
photoContainer.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, теперь всё ОК. Вопрос можно закрывать!

Comment: Заработало во всех браузерах, кроме IE6. Сейчас буду разбираться в чем проблема. Проблема явно в CSS, а не в JavaScript. Подскажите, может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой.